# putting check in span base on ajax request jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an ajax request and i get result i want to check some span but i am wondering why i cant check the span i am putting the correct ID and correct value

HTML

```
<span id='Mediation'></span>

<span id='Conciliation'></span>

<span id='Arbitration'></span>
```

JS

```
console.log(data[i].resolution);
if (data[i].resolution == 'Mediation' && !data[i].resolution == 'undefined') {
    $('#Mediation').html('&#10004;');
}
if (data[i].resolution == 'Conciliation' && !data[i].resolution == 'undefined') {
    $('#Mediation').html('&#10004;');
    $('#Conciliation').html('&#10004;');
}
if (data[i].resolution == 'Arbitration' && !data[i].resolution == 'undefined') {
    $('#Mediation').html('&#10004;');
    $('#Conciliation').html('&#10004;');
    $('#Arbitration').html('&#10004;');
}
```

Another thing that bugs me is why in `console.log` i have undefined value when i have in ajax result the exact value
[This](http://jsfiddle.net/guradio/fn4px0es/) is the working sample.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things:

1. The data that is returned has multiple objects within an array. But only the first object has the  key "resolution". This is the reason that except for the first iteration, you have `undefined` in console log.
2. You make a comparison like this `!data[i].resolution == 'undefined'` which instead should be `data[i].resolution != 'undefined'` which is the reason your if condition never passes.

Comment: Exactly, therefore this should be quite sufficent: http://jsfiddle.net/fn4px0es/4/ (`if (data[0].resolution == 'Conciliation') {`) - or if the `for` is really needed: `/*for i*/ if (data[i].resolution == 'Conciliation') {`

Comment: Will this be ok if more records are return?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan i think `for i` is needed because i might have more data than this one.i tried `/*for i*/ if (data[i].resolution == 'Conciliation') {` but it didnt cover it

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan you can see that in my fiddle i just added the `undefined` when i notice the `undefined in console.log`